# menu on only a single page

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I am not really into all those coding terms, so I am having some difficulties to find answer to my problem. I want to create a single site menu. So if i press on a list item the browser should open an other content but on the same page. I tried using css with targets but everytime i click a new target the tagets will overlap and the old content will not disappear. I tried using Javascript with innerHTML but in javascript i need to write the whole page in a single line (.innerHTML ='websitecode') this will create a horrible overview.

Is there any other possibility to create something like this? Maybe with the require() / involve() function in php?

Thank you

Comment: Why you want to write your whole page in a single lined JS string? Write it in HTML.

Comment: to run a sript while navigating on the page. For example something like music. You can search for the next song while listening to an other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, what I understood is you want menu navigation without loading the content again.

```
`http://codepen.io/ArslanRafique/pen/raZybL`
```

Above is the snippet, I recently developed, simple menu navigation by using simple CSS and HTML. You can achieve simple menu navigation by using HTML label and can swap your views accordingly.

Please have a look at shared snippet, hope it will help you.

Comment: P.S. Your website looks so beautiful :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you would like to create a single page web application:
There are many great javascript frameworks for this, try angular.

https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/building-angularjs-app-tutorial

Put your menu in the header file, and the content you want to replace in to views.

Or use angular UI-router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Answer (score 0):

There are few possibilities to achieve your goal.
The simple and not so elegant one would be to generate the complete content and set anchors on the page. From the menu the user can call the anchors and will be brought to a desired part of the page. Example:

```
<!-- Menu -->
<ul>
    <li><a href="#aboutus">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Page contents -->
<div id="aboutus">This is about us.</div>
<div id="products">Our products.</div>
```

More elegant, sophisticated and professional approach would be creating a SPA (single page application). It would include some techniques like AJAX, where you can load (or remove) contents on the page without refreshing.
There are many modern JS frameworks that can help you, for example AngularJS, ReactJS, etc.

Wikipedia offers also more information on SPA:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Answer (score 0):

So Arlan's version looks a lot prettier, but you can also use javaScript with divs that you can hide or display with functions. You can format the divs in your css with whatever you want. May get a little clunky if you have a long menu...

```
<div id="divOne">This will show some text</div>
<div id="divTwo"><p>This will show even more text</p><p>I may even format it differently</p>
</div>
<div id="divThree">This shows text that is different from the other two</div>

    var formatOne = document.getElementById("button1"); //create handle for first button 
    formatOne.onclick = function() { //add functionality
        document.getElementById("divOne").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("divTwo").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("divThree").style.display = "none";
   }
```

Jsfiddle to show the functionality.

https://jsfiddle.net/lattivalidus/s7a9dLe7/